# Three.js removing seams

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to remove seams where two meshes are connected (under neck)?
[image]

There's how I load models:

```
var model = new THREE.Object3D();
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load( "models/one.js", function(geometry, material){
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() );
    model.add( mesh );
} );    
jsonLoader.load( "models/two.js", function(geometry, material){
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
    model.add( mesh );
    model.scale.set(4,4,4);
    model.position.y = -3.5;
    scene.add(model);
} );
```

Comment: No. It depends on your triangles and how they are arranged. If you don't have smooth surface, the renderer sure won't smooth it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the face normals are very different at the border of both meshes, where they meet. That's why the lighting looks very different at the border, thus giving a seam-like appearance. I believe if you adjust your models so that the normals at the edge neck point to the same direction, so that the lights receive a smooth transition. Allow me to demonstrate with a poorly drawn picture:

[image: Parallel normals]

Three.js will shade the first example so that light appears as in a sharp corner, based on the direction of normals. Second should be smooth.

How to accomplish this depends on the modelling software used to create the meshes. If you use Three.js to auto-generate normals for you (normals not included in the model data), I'm not sure how to fix it easily (maybe merging the geometries, combining shared vertices, then letting three.js regenerate the normals could work then).